# databricks function - how to test without inputting column

Tags: databricks

right now I have an azure databrick function that works successfully.  I feed it a column from a dataframe as a parameter and I can view the results successfully.

however, while I am developing I would like to feed it a parameter I type, such as '202401'.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, substr

def CreateBloombergSymbol(pctym):
    
    digitMonth = pctym[4:6]
    digitYear1 = pctym[3:4]
    digitYear2 = pctym[2:4]
    
    match_dict = {
        "01": "F",
        "02": "G",
        "03": "H",
        "04": "J",
        "05": "K",
        "06": "M",
        "07": "N",
        "08": "Q",
        "09": "U",
        "10": "V",
        "11": "X",
        "12": "Z",
        "foo": "missingValue"
    }
    charMonth = match_dict.get(digitMonth, "foo")                               
    return digitYear2

varMyBloombergFunction = spark.udf.register("CreateBloombergSymbol", CreateBloombergSymbol)
```

when I run it like this... it works

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

dfPos.select(
    #col('*'),
    varMyBloombergFunction(col('pctym')).alias('BloombergSymbol')
).display()
```

when I run it like this... it does not work.  anyone know what i am doing wrong? or misunderstanding?

```
x1 = varMyBloombergFunction('202401')
print(x1)
```

this is the result of it not displaying appropriate result

```
Column<'CreateBloombergSymbol(202401)'>
```